# How to write directly into a vector array <std::vector< std::array

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, visual-c++

I'm trying to write directly into a

`auto tablelisttt = std::make_shared<std::vector< std::array<std::string, 9>>(size);`

```
    for (int j = 1; j <=max; j++)
    {
        //dummy example code
        tablelisttt->operator[0](j)="Hello"; //Only one string at a time in an array 
    }
```

so that data from a database is written directly to the vector array as efficiently / quickly as possible.

but no matter what i try i can't get it to write into the vector array directly with the msvc compiler (the gcc online compilers work )

i use c++19

Comment: What does "I can't" mean? If you get a compilation error, please copy-paste it here.

Comment: `tablelisttt->operator[0](j)` should be `tablelisttt->operator[0][j]` or simply `(*tablelisttt)[0][j]`

Comment: Are you sure `d4XXX` use 1-indexing and not 0-indexing? Do you check index value to avoid out of bound access (is vector empty? is `j < 9`?)?

Comment: Please post some [mcve], the code shown has various things that would prevent it to compile, even if unknown functions are replaced. `std::make_shared<std::vector< std::array<std::string, 9>>(size)` is missing a `>`, `tablelisttt->operator[0](j)` won't compile either. So how should we know that there are not even more differences to your actual code?